# Firestore/Cloud functions: Finding a document in array of document references that match criteria

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Using Firebase Cloud Functions I'd like to search for documents that contain a certain other document in an array of document references. My structure looks as follows;

```
Users 
   name
   email
   cars
      ref to cars/car1 for example
      ref to cars/car2 for example
Cars
   registration
   make
   model
```

There are multiple users and multiple cars. I need to search for users that have a certain 'car' in their car array.

I'm trying to write this in a Cloud Function and have the following;

```
admin.firestore()
              .collection('users')
              .where('cars', 'array-contains', registration)
              .get().then(doc => {
                console.log("TESTING: found the user " + doc.data().email)
                return
              }).catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
              });
```

I know this is currently just searching for the registration string in the array. Is there anyway to search for a specific document reference. I'm using Node.js.

---

Working code to get all the documents that have a document reference in an array;

```
// Notify the owner of the car
            admin.firestore()
              .collection('users')
              .where('cars', 'array-contains', carRef)
              .get().then(snapshot => {
                snapshot.forEach(doc => {
                  console.log("TESTING found the user " + doc.data().email);
                  const message = {
                    notification: {
                      body: 'Your vehicle (' + carReg + ') recieved a report. Tap here to see!',
                    },
                    token: doc.data().cloudMessagingToken
                  };
                  sendMessage(message);
                });
                return
              }).catch(error => {
                console.error("Error finding a user that has the car in their garage");
                console.error(error);
              });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query using reference type fields, you will need to provide a DocumentReference type object to the query.  If you pass a DocumentReference to a car, the query should work.  For example:

```
const ref = admin.firestore().collection('Cars').doc(id)
```

where `id` is the id of the document.

However, you can't search using values of fields inside the referenced document.  Firestore queries only work against data in a single collection at a time.  With the way you have your data organized right now, it's not possible to make a single query for all users who have references to cars with a specific registration string field.  For that query, you would need to also store an array of registration strings for each user that you could query with array-contains.

Yes, this involves duplication of data, and it's called "denormalization".  This is very common in nosql type databases to enable the queries you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so I've stored the ref and then am trying to search by that. I'm still not getting any users being found and there are definitely users with that car in their array. Do you think you could have a look over the code added to the question and see if I'm on the right trace?

Comment: Without seeing all the actual data, it's not really possible to tell for sure.

Comment: Think I've managed to fix it with your help! Will post the working code for others to use in case they find it helpful. Thank you!